# PROOF: RSS equal in both models

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, least-squares

How can I prove that the RSS is the same for the following model:
Y = T + A + u

where

```
  T = β1 + β2Xi + u

  A = α1 + α2Xi + u
```

I think if i can prove that the subtraction of the first one minus the second one, equal 0 then they'd be the same.

Comment: The same *as compared to what?*

Comment: The simple linear regression of $Y=T+A$ on $X$ will give coefficients which are the sum of the corresponding coefficient for $T$ and $A$ on $X$, but the residual sum of squares will usually be smaller